Almacenar datos desde array foreach php usando mysqli
Estoy tratando de almacenar los datos en esos campos con inputs que tienen esto [] (múltiples inputs), son de tipo array.
Estoy tratando de almacenarlos con un foreach pero no me está almacenando la info... En otro ejemplo uso otro tipo de conexión y me funciona perfecto. Acá:
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'contrasena', 'BD'); 
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
// estos inputs son estaticos su valor es asi --------
$id_servicio_c= $_POST['id_servicio_c'];
$numero_servicio_c= $_POST['numero_servicio_c'];
$conducct_c= $_POST['conducct_c'];


foreach(array_keys($_POST['id_servicio_c']) as $key) {
  $product = $_POST['product'][$key]; 
  $qty = $_POST['qty'][$key];
  $price = $_POST['price'][$key];
  $total = $_POST['total'][$key]; 
  $sql =  "INSERT INTO tabla1 (
                    id_servicio_c,
                    numero_servicio_c, 
                    conducct_c, 
                    product,
                    qty,  
                    price, 
                    total                       
                    ) 
                    "."
                    VALUES (
                    '$id_servicio_c',
                    '$numero_servicio_c',
                    '$conducct_c',
                    '$product',
                    '$qty',
                    '$price',
                    '$total'
                    )";
 $mysqli->query($sql);
 }
?>


Según el código $id_servicio_c= $_POST['id_servicio_c']; y más abajo tienes un foreach(array_keys($_POST['id_servicio_c']) as $key). Significa, entonces, que la variable $id_servicio_c es de tipo array. Por supuesto que no puedes meter un array directamente en la base de datos, tal como lo dice la [línea 29], en el $sql. Se necesita conocer la estructura de $_POST para ayudar mejor con el problema.

hola @aeportugal gracias por tu respuesta, es un valor que viene en el formulario pues pensaba que necesita ese valor $_POST['id_servicio_c']) as $key por el uso de AS KEY

Gracias al comentario de aeportugal, puse allí el campo de un array (que llevaba corchete [])
foreach(array_keys($_POST['product']) as $key) {
  $product = $_POST['product'][$key]; 
  $qty = $_POST['qty'][$key];
  $price = $_POST['price'][$key];
  $total = $_POST['total'][$key]; 
  $sql =  "INSERT INTO costos (
                    id_servicio_c,
                    numero_servicio_c, 
                    conducct_c, 
                    product,
                    qty,  
                    price, 
                    total                       
                    ) 
                    "."
                    VALUES (
                    '$id_servicio_c',
                    '$numero_servicio_c',
                    '$conducct_c',
                    '$product',
                    '$qty',
                    '$price',
                    '$total'
                    )";
 $mysqli->query($sql);
 }


Pero no queda claro por qué pusiste [] en tus inputs. ¿Quieres proporcionar información para hacer varios INSERT? Por otra parte, considera blindar tu código contra ataques de Inyección SQL.
